# How do you augment 4 dimensional images?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation

I have a batch of 3000 or so sets of 7 images, each image around 144 by 256 grayscale pixels, and I want to augment each of these images. I know this works with 3d images, example shape- (144, 256, 3), but I am pretty new to data augmentation and am not sure the best way to go about this. One idea I thought of was to go through each set and make a few copies of the image, each copy slightly augmented, but I am not sure how to go about this. Here is the part that I have so far:

```
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential([
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip('horizontal', input_shape=(train_images.shape[1:])),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomZoom(0.1)
])

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(data_augmentation)
model.add(layers.Conv3D(512, (1, 3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(train_images.shape[1:])))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling3D((1, 2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv3D(256, (1, 3, 3),  padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling3D((1, 2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(layers.Conv3D(256, (1, 3, 3),  padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling3D((1, 2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv3D(128, (1, 3, 3),  padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling3D((1, 2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
```

Here is the error message and traceback I am currently getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mason Choi\PycharmProjects\Passion_project\main (test).py", line 50, in <module>
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomZoom(0.1)
  File "C:\Users\Mason Choi\anaconda3\envs\Passion_project\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 517, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mason Choi\anaconda3\envs\Passion_project\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.add(layer)
  File "C:\Users\Mason Choi\anaconda3\envs\Passion_project\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 517, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mason Choi\anaconda3\envs\Passion_project\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 208, in add
    layer(x)
  File "C:\Users\Mason Choi\anaconda3\envs\Passion_project\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 952, in __call__
    input_list)
  File "C:\Users\Mason Choi\anaconda3\envs\Passion_project\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1091, in _functional_construction_call
    inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mason Choi\anaconda3\envs\Passion_project\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 822, in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call
    return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
  File "C:\Users\Mason Choi\anaconda3\envs\Passion_project\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 862, in _infer_output_signature
    self._maybe_build(inputs)
  File "C:\Users\Mason Choi\anaconda3\envs\Passion_project\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 2685, in _maybe_build
    self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
  File "C:\Users\Mason Choi\anaconda3\envs\Passion_project\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\input_spec.py", line 223, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(tuple(shape)))
ValueError: Input 0 of layer random_flip is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: (None, 7, 36, 64, 1)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Let me know if you need any more info!

Answer (score 0):

To apply data augmentations for a 5D tensor of images, you could:

1. Reshape your input images to a 4D tensor of shape `(batch_size * nb_sets, h, w, channels)`.
2. Apply the transformations as usual.
3. Reshape the images back to the 5D tensor of shape `(batch_size, nb_sets, h, w, channels)`.

---

For example, something along the lines of:

```
...
model.add(layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.reshape(x, (-1, 144, 256, 3))))
model.add(data_augmentation)
model.add(layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.reshape(x, (-1, 7, 144, 256, 3))))
...
```

**NOTE:** Not tested.